# How can I catch InterruptedException when making http request with Apache?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, threadpool, interrupt

I have a Callable that makes a http request via Apache library. However, if the request takes too long, I would like to kill the thread. To do this, I can interrupt the Callable, but I need to catch the InterruptedException in order to stop myself. How can I do this?

```
private final class HelloWorker implements Callable<String> {
    private String url;

    public HelloWorker(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public CloseableHttpResponse call() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(getCustomSslConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();

        return httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    }
}

private CloseableResponse getHttpResponse(String url) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    Future<String> future = executorService.submit(new HelloWorker());

    try {  
        // try to get a response within 5 seconds
        return future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // kill the thread
        future.cancel(true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note `future.cancel(true)` doesn't kill the thread because all it does is interrupt the thread, and my code doesn't catch the InterruptedException. However, I cannot figure out how to do this since `httpClient.execute` is blocking, and I cannot divide the work into chunks.

Would it be sufficient to just catch InterruptedException while calling `httpClient.execute()`?

```
    public CloseableHttpResponse call() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(getCustomSslConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();
        try {
            return httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        } catch (InterruptedException) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: a `Future` will catch every `Throwable` you don't catch. `.get()` will give it to you if you need it.

Comment: "However, if the request takes too long, I would like to kill the thread". No you don't. You want to set a timeout.

Comment: Remember to accept this message if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> To do this, I can interrupt the Callable, but I need to catch the InterruptedException in order to stop myself. How can I do this?

You can't.  None of the external methods of the `HttpClient` throw `InterruptedException`.  You cannot catch an exception that is not thrown by the methods.  Interrupting a thread causes *only* those methods that throw `InterruptedException` to throw it.  This includes `Thread.sleep()`, `Object.wait()`, and others.  The rest of the methods must test for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to see the interrupt flag.

I recommend setting http client parameters that set the socket timeouts.  I'm not sure which version of Apache `HttpClient` you are using but we are using 4.2.2 and do something like the following:

```
BasicHttpParams clientParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(clientParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(clientParams, socketTimeoutMillis);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(clientParams);
```

Comment: `java.net.http.HttpClient#send` has Signature public abstract <T> HttpResponse<T>
    send(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler<T> responseBodyHandler)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException;`

Comment: Thanks.  The poster was talking about Apache HttpClient.