# Hystrix: Apache http client requests are not interrupted

Tags: java, timeout, hystrix

I have an apache HTTP client defined as follows:

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = null;
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.TRUE);
httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "ABC");

HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParams, Boolean.TRUE);

SSLSocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();

SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, sf));

//Initialize the http connection pooling
PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);

// Initialize the connection parameters for performance tuning
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(12);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, httpParams);
```

I have a hystrix command `play` and have the following properties enabled:

```
hystrix.command.play.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1
hystrix.command.play.execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout=true
```

The command itself is defined as follows:

```
    @HystrixCommand(groupKey="play_group",commandKey="play")
    public String process(String request) throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Before -  process method : " + request);
        callHttpClient(request);
        System.out.println("After -  process method" + request);
        return "";
    }

    private void callHttpClient(String request) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.co.in");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        System.out.println("Response:" + response);
    }
```

I now try executing the command 5 times in a loop:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContextTest.xml");
        HystrixPlayground obj = ctx.getBean(HystrixPlayground.class);

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try{
                System.out.println(obj.process("test" + i));
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time(ms) : ---->" + (t2 - t1));
```

The timeout is set to 1 milli second, so the process method throws a HystrixRunTimeException. However, the http request continues to execute and prints the "After -  process method" string.

I have seen this behavior consistently for http client requests only. If the http request is replaced by anything else like a thread sleep or a very big for loop, the hystrix thread gets interrupted as expected.

Does anyone have any insight into why this may be happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693335/how-can-i-catch-interruptedexception-when-making-http-request-with-apache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that interrupting a thread in Java does not "force stop" it. Instead, invoking `Thread.interrupt()` just sets a flag which can, but does not have to be interpreted by the running thread. See more here: [What does java.lang.Thread.interrupt() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do)

Apache HTTP client does not interpret this flag (as a socket read operation by the JRE cannot be interrupted). Thus, the HTTP request is not canceled and just completes.

Comment: Has anyone raised this with the Apache httpclient project?

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` does not interrupt socket read operations blocked in JRE native code. This issue has nothing to do with HttpClient.

Comment: That is true. Thanks for the clarification. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that by the past some IO operations, on some plaforms(solaris) could be interrupted using `Thread.interrupt()`. Now that **seems not not possible/specified anymore for java.io**, but still possible with java.nio.
(see [Java bug 4385444](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4385444) and [Java bug 7188233](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7188233) for more details)

So even if [with some platforms/versions it seems still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36698504/5088764) to interrupt a blocking IO with `Thread.interrupt()`, this seems clearly not recommended :

- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-threads-second/1565924185/ch04s05.html#ch04-8-fm2xml
- https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/THI04-J.+Ensure+that+threads+performing+blocking+operations+can+be+terminated

So there is nothing wrong in [httpclient](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2021?jql=project%20%3D%20HTTPCLIENT%20AND%20text%20~%20interrupt). With Hystrix you should `abort()` the request on Hystrix timeout. If you are using fallback, you can call it in `getFallback()`, if not you can call it after you get the result. E.g :

```java
try {
    hystrixCommand.execute();
} catch (HystrixRuntimeException e) {
    switch (e.getFailureType()) {
    case TIMEOUT:
       // supposing you add a getHttpRequest getter on your command.
       hystrixCommand.getHttpRequest().abort();
    }
}
```